# Pass TouchEvent to newly created SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview, touch-event

Is it possible to pass a touch event to a newly created SurfaceView in android 4.0.3 project.

Let me more precise.

I have created a custom OnTouchListener which handles incoming events.
The ACTION_DOWN event instantiates a custom SurfaceView and adds it on top of all other Views (This works fine). The SurfaceView should now handle the ACTON_MOVE and notify a Listener on ACTION_UP. The original OnTouchListener should be removed after the SurfaceView was added.

I have tried to pass the TouchEvent with dispatchTouchEvent but this works only if i do it continously. Is it possible to implement the described behavior and what is the the best way to do it?

Best regards and thank you.

Here is some code:

TouchListener:

```
OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {


    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            surfaceView = new CustomSurfaceView(this.getActivity(), drawer);
            surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
            surfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

            overlayContainer.addView(surfaceView);
            btnView.setOnTouchListener(null);

            return surfaceView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);;

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
};


btnView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
```

SurfaceView:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {

    switch (action) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();

        return true;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        // TODO:notify Listener
        return true;


    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include code in your questions whenever possible, that way people are more likely to be able to give you good quality answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just pass the touchevent to the newly created object. Within that object you should check if the surface is ready or not. Pass true if it was ready so the outter class can also return true etc.

Always pass touchevents down the ladder, never let them originate there.

Comment: Do i have to pass the ACTION_MOVE events continuously to the surfaceView with dispatchTouchEvent in my custom OnTouchListener, or is there a better way which avoids this?

Comment: on my samsung s2 if i drag my finger across the screen a touchevent (move) is released every 4 pixels of movement. So the user moves his finger over the display a lot of touchevents will happen and YES you should pass them all down to the class that needs them